# does React restrict usage of undeclared variables?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Code snippet:

[image]

```
class Box extends React.Component{
  render() {
    params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    abc = params.get('abc');
    console.log(params);
```

Error via "Create React App":

[image]

Why am I getting an error here?

Comment: That's the default linting/strict-mode in create-react-app. But you shouldn't throw variables around willy-nilly; there's a reason this is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In non-strict mode, an assignment to an undeclared symbol is
>   implicitly treated as creating a global variable. In strict mode,
>   that's an error.

I just checked Reacts compiled code and it has `"use strict";` at the top. So yes, React restricts undeclared variables.